# Error querying database when inserting into cpanel phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, insertion

```
<?php
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $mname=$_POST['mname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $college_name=$_POST['college_name'];
    $semester=$_POST['semester'];
    $contact=$_POST['contact'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];


    $dbc = mysql_connect('localhost','XXXX',"XXXX",'XXXXX')
            or die('error connecting to MYSQL server');
    echo kkk;
    $query = "INSERT INTO tab_m_registration(fname, mname, lname, college_name, semester, contact, email)".
            "VALUES(`$fname`, `$mname`, `$lname`, `$college_name`, `$semester`, `$contact`, `$email`)";
            echo $query;
            $result=mysql_query($query,$dbc) or die('error querying database');

            echo $result;

            echo 'Thanx for submitting the form. <br/>';
            mysql_close($dbc);

        ?>
```

Actually I don't understand where is the problem.

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $dbc)
```

is not working I think.

I first tried `mysqli_query()` and it got problem. Then I tried this

```
$result = mysql_query($dbc, $query)
```

and I get an error "argument 1 should be string" in `mysql_query()`.

I swapped the values and finally used this `mysql_query($query, $dbc)`.

It shows the value passing through echo.

But still there's a problem inserting the data in the database table. Please help me out.

Comment: Try enclosing your query variables in quotes instead of back ticks

Comment: Thank you for the clue.But actually i am not getting the thing what are you telling about.Can you please show me an example?

Comment: I have replaced the backticks with single quotes but,problem still exists.

Comment: Once upon a time the `mysql_` functions have been deprecated...

Comment: You need to do some reading my friend. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp. By passing un-sanitised variables you are leaving yourself open to injections !!

Comment: Thank you for idea of un-sanitised variables.But how can i solve the problem of mysql_ .If it is deprecated,what are the alternatives??Please help.

Comment: There have actually two problems.1st one is user privilege and 2nd one is that backticks.Thank you.it is solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to investigate the error further (get some error messages). You could use a try/catch block to get more error messages (are the fields all set up, etc.). Consider the following code but bear in mind that it is still wide open to SQL injection (just to get an error message):

```
try {
    $db = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database");
    if ($db->connect_errno)
        throw new Exception("Connection to the database failed: " . $db->connect_error);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tab_m_registration (`fname`, `mname`, `lname`, `college_name`, `semester`, `contact`, `email`) ";
    $sql .= "VALUES(`$fname`, `$mname`, `$lname`, `$college_name`, `$semester`, `$contact`, `$email`)";

    if (!$db->query($sql))
        throw new Exception("Error Inserting Data " . $db->error);

    mysqli_close($db);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: <p>Warning: mysqli_connect(): (42000/1044): Access denied for user 'isoftech_ppd'@'localhost' to database 'isoftech_coaching' in /home/isoftech/public_html/reginsert_interest.php on line 53</p>

<p>Here line 53 means:$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "isoftech_ppd", "XXXX", "isoftech_coaching");</p>


<p>Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/isoftech/public_html/reginsert_interest.php on line 60</p>


<p>Here line 60 means:if (!$db->query($sql))</p>

Comment: Well, there you go, you are lacking permissions. This needs to be fixed first!

Comment: Please tell me how??I already selected all privileges in the database.

Comment: @ParthaPratimDeb This is a site for programming and code not a site to find people doing your work :-)

Comment: Its solved.Actually i there have no privilege for the user.I set it.Thank you.

Comment: @ParthaPratimDeb: Consider accepting an answer then.